# Android Market - developer console: marketing enabled / disabled?

Tags: android, google-play

In the Android Market developer console, on the profile of my app, there is a box which can be checked or unchecked allowing to `disable` or `enable` marketing.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The wording is pretty clear. It says:

"Do not promote my application except in Android Market and in any Google-owned online or mobile properties."

Meaning if you opt out (i. e. if the box is checked), entities other than Google (e. g. mobile carriers) won't showcase your app in their ads. I don't see why would anyone opt out, though.

To let them promote your app anywhere where possible, leave the box unchecked.

Comment: so should i leave it checked or unchecked if i do NOT want to opt out ?

Comment: Unchecked. Means - yes, you can promote my app anywhere.

Comment: Is this free of cost?

Comment: The checkbox is free either way. The Google Play account itself is paid.